# Implementar um Layout no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

estou querendo implementar um layout assim no Android Studio, procurei já no Google, mas não soube me referir a esse tipo de barra que quero fazer, ai fiz essa imagem. Acho que está bem auto explicativo na imagem, quando o usuário clickar vai abrir o texto daquela barra onde ele clickou e quando clickar novamente vai fechar minimizando a barra.

[image: Layout]

Comment: Procura por android expandable/collapsible views/layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acho que você esta procurando por algo assim 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZxZIFnJ9jE

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você está procurando uma recyclerview expandable, esse componente funciona bem para tal: https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view